# Can't get UiAutomator to work - classes do not appear, UiAutomator2 driver absent

Tags: java, appium, android-uiautomator

I am using Idea and Android Studio, writing my test with Appium, need to add UIautomator to my project, I added dependency statement to build.gradle file.
compile group: 'androidx.test.uiautomator', name: 'uiautomator', version: '2.2.0-alpha4'

But I can't see any UI automator classes

Also I added following capability  capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");

How can I use it? UiDevice search founds nothing

Comment: Hi Eugene, wellcome to SO. Please, read this link. http://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/android-uiautomator/

Answer (score 0):

set `skipServerInstall = False` in DesiredCapabilities and you will get the latest UiAutomator2 from the appium. Once the test ran successfully for one time, you can set that to`True` again

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/appium/appium-uiautomator2-driver#driverserver), the correct capability to set to make appium install the latest uiautomator2 server is `skipServerInstallation`, so set its value to `false`.